# can i cut a large strip board into a smaller one?

Tags: stripboard

I need a 17 hole by 8 hole strip board. I could only buy a much larger one. Can I cut the larger one to the size I need without destroying it? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a strip board? Could you include a photo or a link to a product web page?

Comment: Ruler and knife. First score it a few times (on the copper side) then break it.

Comment: Miniature hacksaw also works, provided the board is correctly clamped - sandwich it with pieces of thicker wood, exposing only the bit near the cut.

Answer (score 2):

Use a ruler or other straight edge to guide a craft knife. Make many passes cutting a little bit at a time. After the cut looks to be reasonably deep you can bend the board and it will break along the cut. You can use sandpaper to clean up the edge.

If you are cutting across traces you might need to make a few knife passes on the back to ensure the traces are all cut before breaking the board.

Comment: Awesome!
Thank you!

Comment: +1 for scoring both sides first.

Answer (score 0):

I cut printed wiring prototype boards with a dremel tool and cutoff wheel. It is a slow process, if you have a lot of them to cut, you might look for a quicker method.

It will create a lot of dust, best to do it in the garage or outside.

Depending on your skill level, you may need to use sandpaper to clean-up the cut.

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/Busboard-ST2-Traditional-Stripboard-Prototyping/dp/B00LLQFRAU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LLQFRAU)

Edit: I have used the knife scoring method also. My success rate was not 100%. I use a dremel now.

Comment: an engraver bit (looks like a twisty ice cream cone) will allow you to MUCH more quickly score the PCB (as a knife score should in a perfect world) and do a clean snap than will the tiny cut-off wheels. I usually put it in a vice and run it along the edge front and back. I can do a 6" board in 5 or 10 seconds in this manner, and they've always snapped clean.

Comment: @dandavis - I would like to buy one. Can you please tell me the Dremel number? The tips that they refer to as engraving don't match your description.

Comment: well my bits and mind are both jumbled up... the tiny circular saw blade works as well, but what i like best are like the bottom 3 on the left here:  https://i.imgur.com/E7e2mDYl.png , though honestly, almost all of those bits pictured could be used. the pointed ones are easy to trace along the vice edge at a 45deg angle, but a round one will work too, just with a thicker no mans land. oscillating saws work well too, for scoring or full-out cutting.

Answer (score 0):

I cut thousands of stripboards of many sizes with a fine-toothed hacksaw and a squaring holder. But only one every day.
Some are made from fiberglass (Veroboard) and others are made from cheap stuff. The cheap ones warp.

Answer (score 0):

Score the copper side with a knife, then break it. Works fine 99 times out of 100.